# Jump to row number

Tags: php, odbc

I have successfully connected my php script to a transbase database with odbc. Here's a simple question I am not able to find an answer: how can I jump to a specific row number in a result set?

EDIT: This is how I'm going through the result set `while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rid))` right now, but I would want to start only from row number 1000 for example without fetching all 999 until that row.

Comment: usually there's a "seek"-type operation to do this.

Comment: do you have a code example of what your are doing now? What method are you using to access the odbc connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per PHP manual, second argument of odbc_fetch_array allow you to fetch row by number.

```
array odbc_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $rownumber ] )
```

See Manual for more details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-array.php

Comment: @slash197 it's fine and happens sometime

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PDO then you can use [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to return all the rows into an array, which you can then access by index

```
$rows = $results->fetchAll();
$row = $rows[5]; // get row 6 (index starts at 0)
```